# React, TypeScript - Using non-React objects to inject components into component tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

I'm working on a React Typescript project. A very simplified version of the project is below. I'm trying to use more traditional polymorphism here where I have components returned from vanilla Typescript objects (not React components) that are rendered in the component tree. The reason I want to do this is so that I can have polymorphic classes that I change at runtime and that manage their own state and business logic.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

class ClickCounter {
  private count: number;
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }
  IncrementCount() {
    this.count += 1;
  }
  GetCount(): number {
    return this.count;
  }
}

interface Operation {
  HandleMouseDown(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void;
  GetComponents(): JSX.Element[];
}

class ClickCounterOperation implements Operation {
  private clickCounter: ClickCounter;
  constructor() {
    const counter: ClickCounter = new ClickCounter();
    this.clickCounter = counter;
  }

  HandleMouseDown(_: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void {
    this.clickCounter.IncrementCount();
  }

  GetComponents(): JSX.Element[] {
    const count: number = this.clickCounter.GetCount();
    return [<div>you have clicked {count} times</div>];
  }
}

export type AppState = {
  currentOperation: Operation;
};

export class App extends React.Component<{}, AppState> {
  constructor(props = {}) {
    super(props);
    const initialOperation: Operation = new ClickCounterOperation();
    this.state = {
      currentOperation: initialOperation,
    };
    this.HandleMouseDown = this.HandleMouseDown.bind(this);
  }

  HandleMouseDown(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    console.log("Dispatching mouse down event to current operation");
    this.state.currentOperation.HandleMouseDown(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" onMouseDown={this.HandleMouseDown}>
        {this.state.currentOperation.GetComponents()}
        <div>some other stuff to show</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In the example above everything will render initially, but not after the count is updated. This is because react has no way of knowing that the state has changed and that a rerender is needed. What I'm currently doing is forcing React to rerender by passing down a `RefreshOperationState` callback to the `Operation` object that will call the `App.setState()` method but this feels very ugly and I don't want to do this.

Any way to achieve this kind of traditional polymorphism with React and have non-React objects inject components into the component tree and have the components update when appropriate? I understand what I am trying to do is not following the common React patterns of using Flux/Redux and having all/most app state in a store/s, but I'd like to make this app in a less functional and more OOP pattern where objects store their own state and are called polymorphicly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, mixing paradigms might be more trouble than it's worth. React relies on object reference equality to handle its rendering logic. Since you're mutating objects instead of creating new ones, it will never know to update.

Another rule of React state is that it is only data (never behavior and definitely not JSX), and you're trying to use both.

You could make components which use hooks like these, and then let your parent component choose how it composes itself based on what kind of Operation you want.

```
const useClickCounter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const incCount = setCount(count + 1);
  return [incCount, count];
};
```

The only other thing I've done is use the observable pattern on the class objects and have a React context in between which observes them and sends the updated state into the React component. The React context provider will cause all consumers beneath it to rerender with fresh state.

```
  public subscribe = (fn: (state) => void) => {
    this.observers.push(fn);
  }
  private update = async () => {
    // Give new state to the Context which is subscribed
    this.observers.forEach(fn => fn(state));
  }
```

PS: if you're familiar with Redux, you could start with something like this:

```
const ClickCounter = () => {
  const value = useSelector(selectedClickCounter);

  return <div>{value}</div>;
};

const operations = {
  clickCounter: {
    RenderComponent: ClickCounter,
    onPressDispatchData: { type: "increment-counter" },
  },
};

const OperationHandler = () => {
  const [currentOperation, setCurrentOperation] = useState(operations.clickCounter);

  return <HandleMouse {...currentOperation} />;
};

const HandleMouse = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="App" onMouseDown={props.onPressDispatchData}>
          {props.RenderComponent}
          <div>some other stuff to show</div>
        </div>
      );
};
```

Comment: Hi @windowsill thanks for your suggestions. Can't exactly see how the second example would work. Would you be able to adapt my code example with this pattern??

Comment: I've been thinking about this problem for a while and I don't think it's worth pursuing this approach. Systems in React are built via composition, not polymorphism. Logic is encapsulated into components and further into hooks which are composed. If you have to trick the React re-render mechanism, why use React at all? That's what makes it reactive.